# how can I make user able to share app using more than one communication app?

Tags: android, hyperlink, share, communication, sharing

when I used the following code , the user was able to select a communication app (such as WhatsApp) just one time ,to share the app link.
next times this communication app is selected by default, and user has no choice to select any other communication app.

```
public static void shareApp(Context context) {
final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check cool App at:" +"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has been asked many times, so you'll probably get downvoted quickly, but I answered below for you. Next time, try googling more first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the chooser intent:

```
String title = "Your Chooser Title"
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title));
```